# For loop with SearchCursor stops after first iteration

Tags: arcpy, cursor, select-by-attribute, for-loop

I'm trying to iteratively select and export a layer using *da.SearchCursor*, but the loop stops after the first iteration. Here is the code:

```py
arcpy.env.workspace = ScratchGDB #
infc= "PA" 
field = 'UniqueID'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(infc, "infcLyr")

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc, field): 
    iterateValue = row[0]
    exp = field + " = '" + iterateValue + "'"
    outfc = ScratchGDB + iterateValue
    if arcpy.Exists(outfc):
        print ("skip - output exists") # skip row if it has been exported already
    else:
        selectRow = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("infcLyr", "NEW_SELECTION", exp)
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("infcLyr", outfc)
```

However, when I use a similarly structured code, but instead of exporting, I just printed the output path, the loop worked fine:

```py
arcpy.env.workspace = ScratchGDB #
infc= "PA" 
field = 'UniqueID'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(infc, "infcLyr")

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(infc, field): 
    iterateValue = row[0]
    exp = field + " = '" + iterateValue + "'"
    outfc = ScratchGDB + iterateValue
    if arcpy.Exists(outfc):
        print ("skip - output exists") # skip row if it has been exported already
    else:
        print(outfc)
```

Update:
I tried to set the `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput` to `FALSE` following the suggestion by @Emil Brundage. The loop still stops after both `SelectLayerByAttribute_management` and `CopyFeatures_Management`  run for the first time. 
Note that the first part of the `if` statement loops with no problem; i.e., if there are multiple existing outputs, the loop will skip all of them. It only stops after the `select` and `copy` tools run through their first input row.

Comment: Try adjusting your whereclause : `exp = """{} = {}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(infc, field), iterateValue)` (or `exp = """{} = '{}'"""format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(infc, field), iterateValue)` if your field is string).

Comment: @smiller thank you! Updated, and it still doesn't loop :(

Comment: You're doing evil things with the selection buffer of a layer while iterating the layer. I should certainly hope that doesn't work.

Comment: It would make more sense to first determine your unique values using the cursor (hint: use a set), then loop over those values to select from your layer and export

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput` set to True. With each iteration you are copying over whatever you have `ExportBuffer` set as. Currently you have a single feature class that's been copied over with each iteration, giving the appearance that the loop only iterated one row. You'll need to update your output feature class name in variable `ExportBuffer` with each iteration to a unique name to prevent copying over the previous loop's results.

Comment: My apologies - I changed some parameters from my original code before posting this question but forgot to change `ExportBuffer` to 'outfc'; it's now updated in my question.